# Is there a way to create a check if user is logged in without any redirections

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and Im struggling to make a function inside my project.
I want to check if the user is logged in to view a link (URL) that only logged in users can see, however I don't want to achieve this without any redirects.

So for example, if I share a link ([www.example.com/devices](http://www.example.com/devices)) with User A that shows x amount of devices on the website (you have to be logged in to view that screen) the link shows [www.example.com/devices](http://www.example.com/devices) when I share the link, when the User A visits the link and even after logging the URL is still the same and the view of that page is now visible to User A.

I have tried using CanActivate, CanLoad (which are deprecated) This simply checks if user is logged in but I still somehow can't manage to achieve this effect without any redirection.

I think the best way to achieve this is to load in the page, make it not viewable when the user is not logged in (CanActive), force to log in with a modal(?) and keep the URL the same during whole process (of course)